# App crashing in Ionic view when saving image as Base64

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently ran into a problem with my Ionic application when trying to save a picture.

I am using ngcordova plugin for capturing the image, and saving it in my scope as an base64 string.

I have chosen to use localstorage to store our pictures, since they will be loew quality images, that are not very important.

**The method taking the picture**

```
    $scope.takePictureFront = function(){
  var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 10,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
  };
  var success = function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      /*
       remember to set the image ng-src in $apply,
       i tried to set it from outside and it doesn't work.
       */
      $scope.cameraPicFront = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
      alert('Inserting front ');

    });
  };
  var failure = function(message){
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  };
  //call the cordova camera plugin to open the device's camera
  navigator.camera.getPicture( success , failure , cameraOptions );
};
```

**The object to be saved to localstorage**

```
  var newCustomer = {
    firstname: $scope.customer.firstname(),
    lastname: $scope.customer.lastname(),
    title: $scope.customer.title(),
    phone: $scope.customer.phone(),
    cellphone: $scope.customer.cellphone(),
    email: $scope.customer.email(),
    timeStamp: today,
    metAt: $scope.conferencePicked,
    addedBy : $scope.userLoggedIn,
    imageFront : $scope.cameraPicFront,
    imageBack : $scope.cameraPicBack,
    comment: $scope.customer.comment(),
    interests : $scope.selected

};
```

**How the array of objects is saved to localstorage**

```
$scope.storedJSON = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['data'] || '{"companies":[],"customers":[]}');
        $scope.storedJSON.customers.push(newCustomer);
        $scope.storedJSON.companies.push(newCompany);
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify($scope.storedJSON);
        window.localStorage['data'] = jsonData;
        $state.go('tab.search');
```

The app idles, and then crashes, or seizes to respond when i try to insert the date, on ipad, tablet, and android device.

Any recommendations ?

**EDIT**

I found a workaround for this. Even the great phones, and tablets i tried this on are having problems, uderstandably, with saving such a file in localstorage.

I edited the options of the camera plugin, and are now saving a smaller image, with lower taget resolution, and everything seems to work fine. Just for anyone stumbling over this deserted question in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a memory leak in the application. Since I don't know how your app functions, that'll be my best guess. Another thing you can try is to check if LocalStorage is allowed; there have been many memory violations when you try to use LocalStorage (personal experience).

What I can recommend you to do is to save the base64 to a text file; this will not hamper your application's performance as Read/Write operations are really memory-light. :)

Have a look:

```
$scope.saveFileToDataStorate = function() {

    var data = JSON.stringify( newCustomer );

    $cordovaFile.writeFile( cordova.file.dataDirectory, 'userDetails.txt', data )
        .then( function( suc ){

            alert( 'File Saved! You can now try and open it.' );

        }, function( error ){ alert( error.code ); });

};
```

Remember to include the `$cordovaFile` dependency in your Controller.